# queue issue due to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I made a simple GUI with a push button in SWING. The push button does the following:

```
private void pushButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       SendInformation(); //a Listener function receives this information
       UseListenerValuesToDoSomething();
 }
```

However this is failing because the listener does not execute until the end of `pushButtonActionPerformed`. By that time `UseListenerValuesToDoSomething` has already returned `null`.

So I think there is an event queue in JFrame that causes the pushButton to execute before my listener. If this is the case, is there a way to add my second function to the queue? That way my second function will execute after receiving the information from the Listener function.

Edit: I am not sure my actual code will help but here it is. It won't compile because you need the program and the API but I hope it gives a better idea of what is happening

```
private void tradeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
        IBProgramInstance.connection.reqHistoricalData(1,contract1,...);
        IBProgramInstance.connection.reqHistoricalData(2,contract2,...);

        findMostActiveContract();

        IBProgramInstance.connection.reqHistoricalData(3,mostActiveContract,...);
}
```

`IBProgramInstance.connection` is an EClientSocket connection to the API InteractiveBrokers and `reqHistoricalData`is their method to request historical data from the api. The actual documentation for the method is [here](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide/java/reqhistoricaldata.htm#HT_reqHistoricalData). The documentation for `.connect` is [here](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide/java/java_eclientsocket_methods.htm) Note that `.connect` is the variable I named for the `EClientSocket` instance.

The listener is called when `reqHistoricalData` is run, but in my code, for some reason it doesn't get called until after the pushButton has been completed.

```
public void findMostActiveContract(){

   int largest = 0;
   int largestKey = 0;

   //volumes is a HashMap that fills a key and the volume of a contract through the Listener. 
   //Thus I need the Listener to run before this function runs. 

   Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> it2 = volumes.entrySet().iterator();  

   // use iterator to determine which contract has largest volume.

   while(it2.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry2 = it2.next();
        if (entry2.getValue()>largest){
            largest = entry2.getValue();
            largestKey = entry2.getKey();
        }
   }

   mostActiveContract = contractList.get(largestKey);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   And use real & descriptive class names, not `A` & `B`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok, I'll edit, but I already tried to make it as simple as possible...

Comment: is there a way to add to this queue? not, only programatically 1. by using Swing Action setEnabled() or 2. by creating own semaphore

Comment: I thought you were going to post an SSCCE?  All I see in the edit is a code snippet.

Comment: this code could be works for data stored in memory, use Runnable#Thread / SwingWorker for all tasks outside data stored in memory, notice then in this case (nobody knows whats SendInformation(); == reason for SSCCE) Swing GUI will be freeze untill all code will be executed

Comment: @AndrewThompson crap, I only read Short so I changed my code thinking it was too long and not descriptive enough. the Listener function is actually an API so it's hard to create a short compilable example. You would need to download the program and the related API before you could have it compile... The SendInformation is a function that sends a request to the program if that helps clarify anything...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
private void pushButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       A();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        B();
       }
  });
 }
```

Or use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in you own way.I hope it works.
Thankyou.

Comment: I think you must to post `evt` to another ActionListener or Swing Action, then you can to sent / invoke number of separate / indenpendent code block based on any condintions